# MySQL Event not performing task as per scheduled?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created event logging as `root` user and `GLOBAL event_scheduler` is also `ON`
My event procedure query is:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
    EVENT `near_end_warranty` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
    DO BEGIN

        DECLARE numrow int;
        SELECT COUNT(id) FROM equipments WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW(),warranty_end_date)<5 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW(),warranty_end_date)>0 INTO numrow;

        IF numrow>0 THEN
        INSERT INTO notifications (eq_id,start_date,end_date,name,type,message,created_by,modified_by,created_on,modified_on)
        SELECT eq_id,warranty_start_date,warranty_end_date,'warranty','ending soon','warranty ends soon for','System','System',NOW(),NOW()
        FROM equipments WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW(),warranty_end_date)<5 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW(),warranty_end_date)>0;
        END IF;

    END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

and my event status is:

```
Db:db_medisup
Name:near_end_warranty
Definer:root@localhost
Time zone:SYSTEM
Type:RECURRING
Execute at:NULL
Interval value:1
Interval field:HOUR
Starts:2015-05-08 07:11:09
Ends:NULL
Status:ENABLED
Originator:1
character_set_client:utf8
collation_connection:utf8_general_ci
Database Collation:latin1_swedish_ci
```

I am trying to get multiple rows from equipment table as per condition and insert into notifications table on hourly basis.I created this event on 07:11,Its 9:52 already and hasn't inserted any rows to notification table yet.warranty_end date:2015-05-20 on two rows of equipment table and today's date is 2015-05-08,so two rows must be added to notification table.What may be the problem here?

Comment: is the scheduler actually running? `show variables like %event%`

Comment: how to check the variable,I have posted event status on the post already?

Comment: you just run the above command. you can look at an event status, even if the scheduler is off

Answer (score 0):

I Actually found the exact problem,there was slight mistake in field name of table and on query,I have now solved it and everything is running perfectly.